# Updating heroku django deployed site with new commits to github repo

Tags: python, django, heroku, github

Say I have deployed a django website on heroku through a github repository. (For deployment I simply clicked on the deploy button here - https://github.com/AmmsA/theresumator#theresumator---using-django-resumator.) I now update the repository with new commits.

Q: How can I make changes in the deployed website from the repository without losing the data already present on the repository.

Comment: You mean the data saved in Heroku Postgresql right ?

Comment: @Raja Simon how do I push the changes to the heroku's app. Is there an option to prevent it from building the db again?

Answer (score 1):

When you are pushing the fresh commits `git push heroku master` or via git hook `git push origin master` -- these nothing to do with heroku database.

But this will run this command when build `python manage.py migrate` so if you are changed something in the migrations definetly db schema get alter not the values stored in there.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I didn't understand. Say I have logined with `$ heroku login`. Now, the site that I deployed has a name `xyz.herokuapp.com`. How do I push to the relevant app?

Answer (score 0):

Just set your remote project:

heroku git:remote -a

And then, push your project on Heroku:
git push heroku main

I've written an article on it. You can see that. https://medium.com/@sreebash/how-to-update-previous-deployed-project-on-heroku-c778d555cd8a